# Produto entre vetores

Tags: python, python-3.x, array, lista

O usuário escolhe a quantidade de posições de dois vetores e faz o produto entre eles e exibe na lista o resultado, o código que fiz está abaixo

```
v1 = int(input("Digite a quantidade de posições do seu vetor: "))

lista1 = []

for i in range(v1):

  lista1.append(int(input("Informe o valor da posição %d: " % (i+1))))

vetor1 = lista1

v2 = int(input("Digite a quantidade de posições do seu vetor: "))

lista2 = []

for i in range(v2):

  lista2.append(int(input("Informe o valor da posição %d: " % (i+1))))

vetor2 = lista2

lista3 = []

if len(vetor1) == len(vetor2):

  p = vetor1 * vetor2

  p = lista3

else:

  print("Não é possível calcular o produto escalar de vetores com dimensões distintas.")
```

Mensagem de erro:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-75-a40e9ce08c1c> in <module>()

     11 lista3 = []

     12 if len(vetor1) == len(vetor2):

---> 13   p = vetor1 * vetor2

     14   p = lista3

     15 else:

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

Answer (score 2):

Não existe uma implementação de multiplicação entre sequências no python, por isso a mensagem de erro.

Você pode calcular o produto escalar usando a função [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) para iterar sobre as duas listas "ao mesmo tempo" e multiplicando os seus valores.

```
produto_escalar = [a * b for a, b in zip(vetor_1, vetor_2)]
```

Acima estou usando [`list comprehensions`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html?#list-comprehensions) para gerar a lista de resultado, mas você poderia criar uma lista e inserir os valores manualmente.

```
produto_escalar = []
for a, b in zip(vetor_1, vetor_2):
    produto_escalar.append(a * b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá,

Pelo que eu compreendi, o problema está na tentativa de multiplicar diretamente os vetores. Como tais vetores estão representados por listas, esta operação não é possível de forma direta. Uma saída possível é a seguinte, com a realização das multiplicações de maneira isolada entre os valores de cada vetor:

```
v1 = int(input("Digite a quantidade de posições do seu vetor: "))
lista1 = []
for i in range(v1):
  lista1.append(int(input("Informe o valor da posição %d: " % (i+1))))
vetor1 = lista1
v2 = int(input("Digite a quantidade de posições do seu vetor: "))
lista2 = []
for i in range(v2):
    lista2.append(int(input("Informe o valor da posição %d: " % (i+1))))
vetor2 = lista2
lista3 = []
print(vetor1)
print(vetor2)
if len(vetor1) == len(vetor2):
    n = 0
    for c in vetor1:
        lista3.append(vetor1[n] * vetor2[n])
        n = n + 1
    print(f'O produto escalar do vetor informado corresponde a', sum(lista3))
else:
    print("Não é possível calcular o produto escalar de vetores com dimensões distintas.")
```